# Why does the recurrence equation for QuickSort consider all the elements in the array?

Tags: algorithm-analysis, recurrence-relation, recursion, quicksort

I have been taught that `QuickSort` has the following recurrence equation in the best case:

$T(n) = \begin{cases} c & \text{if } n=1 \\ 2\ T(\frac{n}{2}) + c \cdot n & \text{if } n>1 \end{cases}$

where $c \in \Theta(1)$ and $c \cdot n \in \Theta(n)$. As well for the general case:

$T(n) = \begin{cases} c & \text{if } n=1 \\ T(q) + T(n-q) + c \cdot n & \text{if } n>1 \end{cases}$

Moreover, the algorithm used in the lecture was the following:

```
Procedure QuickSort(A[p,...,r])
    if p < r
        q = Partition(A, p, r)
        QuickSort(A, p, q-1)
        QuickSort(A, q+1, r)
```

As you can see, the recursive calls don't take care of the pivot element $q$. I understand this occurs as `Partition` moves elements around until the pivot is where it should be is the array ordered. The following is the `Partition` algorithm:

```
Function Partition(A[p,...,r], p, r)
    x = A[r]
    i = p-1
    for j = p to j = r-1 do
        if A[j] <= x
            i = i+1
            Exchange(A[i], A[j])
    Exchange(A[i+1], A[r])
    return i+1
```

My question is: *Why do the recurrence equations assume the algorithm takes all the elements of the array (let it be $n$) if the actual algorithm only takes $n-1$ elements?*

Why can't it be the following?

$T(n) = \begin{cases} c & \text{if } n=1 \\ 2\ T(\frac{n-1}{2}) + c \cdot n & \text{if } n>1 \end{cases}$

Or, more generally, this one?

$T(n) = \begin{cases} c & \text{if } n=1 \\ T(q) + T(n-q-1) + c \cdot n & \text{if } n>1 \end{cases}$

Comment: You're right, your recurrence is the correct one. But both have the same solution and the second is more cumbersome, so the first is often used.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I guess they use the first one as it yields the same result and it's *easier* to prove. You see, I made the proof of the second one just to see if it yielded the same result... Indeed, it does, but it's a bit more difficult.

Comment: How would you prove the first one? It's incorrect. It should be impossible to prove.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I assume you meant by "first one" the first that appears in my question.

Comment: Right, that's what I meant.

Comment: The first two equations were actually the ones given in class. For those ones the teacher gave us a proof based on recursive substitution. As for the third one, I made a proof based on what the teacher did.

Comment: You mean that they're easier to calculate with, to estimate the solution asymptotically. *Prove* is an overloaded term in this context, since it's not clear what you prove - the recurrence itself, or its asymptotics.

Comment: Ah, I see. So those "proofs" are actually *calculations* of complexity, aren't they?

Comment: It's better to think of them in that way.

Comment: "as it takes Θ(n) time, can be represented with any function - for instance, c⋅n" -- but this is not always true! It's an admissible simplification if you are only after $\Theta$-bounds, though. But well, now your sentence is correct at least.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you're looking at the behaviour of the algorithm as $n\to\infty$, the difference between $n$ and $n-1$ becomes negligible. The simpler form is easier to deal with and it gives the same answer.

Comment: Also, assuming that $T$ is monotone (which can be proved by induction), the formula gives an (almost tight) upper bound on the running time.

Comment: Now I understand. As with $O(n+c) = O(n)$, in this problem it's seen that taking care of the *real* partition is almost negligible as $n \to \infty$. And so, the complexity is the same.

Comment: "the difference between n and n−1 becomes negligible" -- note that this is only an a posteriori argument. Once we *know* the solution of the precise recurrence is in $\Theta(n \log n)$ we can make it, but not before. For instance, $(n-1)! \in o(n!)$; we need a suitable upper bound at least in order to exclude too-fast-growing functions.

Answer (score 4):

> As well for the general case: [recurrence with $q$]

Note how $q$ remains a free variable here; that's bad. It's not the same $q$ for every recursive call, and either way you can not really solve the recurrence. You need to let $q$

- be $0$ or $n - 1$ for the worst case,
- be $n/2 \pm 1$ for the best case, or
- sum over $\sum_{q=0}^{n-1}$ and take the average by multiplying with $\frac{1}{n}$ for the average case (under the random permutation model).

  Note that more involved arguments are needed to see that this last one is actually correct, in particular that the recursion maintains the random model.

As such, the form with $q$ is an intermediate step only.

> Why can't it be the following [with $n-1$ instead of $n$]?

It can, and it should. However, the recurrence may be easier to solve if you use $n$ instead of $n-1$. The simplification can be justified if you

- are only interested in asymptotics and
- establish that

  $\qquad\displaystyle \frac{T(n)}{T(n-1)} \in O(1)$

  as $n \to \infty$. This is the case if $T$ is "smooth" and does not grow too fast.